# Code unexpectedly fails to compile. Why?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, inner-classes, move-constructor

Take a look a the following code example which uses class `uncopiable` similar to `boost::noncopyable`:

```
#include <vector>

class uncopiable {
    using self = uncopiable;
protected:
    uncopiable() {}
    ~uncopiable() {}
    uncopiable(const self&) = delete;
    self& operator=(const self&) = delete;
};

struct A {
    struct B : uncopiable {
        using self = B;

        B() {
        }

        B(B&&) = default;
        self& operator=(B&&) = default;

        ~B() {
        }
    };

    A() { v.emplace_back(); }
    ~A() {}

private:
    std::vector<B> v;
};

int main () {}
```

Since I wanted to make inner class move only I explicitly specified its move constructor and assignment operator to be default ones but also since I've heard that it's a good practice to specify all of the "special member functions" in such case I inherited it from `uncopiable`. The problem is that compilation fails with every compiler and something similar to the following error message is displayed (this message is excerpt from the clang one):

> /usr/include/c++/v1/memory:1645:31: error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'A::B'
>
> ...
>
> main.cpp:26:10: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::vector >::emplace_back<>' requested here
>
> main.cpp:19:3: note: copy constructor is implicitly deleted because 'B' has a user-declared move constructor

It could be fixed by removing inheritance (copy operations would still not be created). But writing copy operations to be explicitly deleted inside class after that is also okay.

My questions are: why does it happen? Could it be considered a deficiency of disabling constructors/assignment operators through inheritance of helper classes?

Comment: Your `noncopiable` class is also implicitly `nonmovable`, therefore `B` is nonmovable as well. `= default` explicitly requests the implicit definition which in this case is deleted. (Essentially, defaulting special member functions is simply a way of altering their declaration, not their definition.)

Comment: @dyp Nice, I've been using such class for a while but since previous version of MSVC didn't allow to specify move operations as `default`, all of my usages worked fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your `uncopiable` class is not moveable. Therefore the `default` move constructor / assignment operator of the derived class try to use the `delete`d copy versions.

```
static_assert(std::is_move_constructible<uncopiable>::value, "");  // fails
static_assert(std::is_move_assignable<uncopiable>::value, "");     // fails
```

The reason for this is § 12.8 ¶ 9:

> If the definition of a class `X` does not explicitly declare a move constructor, one will be implicitly declared as defaulted if and only if
>
> - `X` does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
> - `X` does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
> - `X` does not have a user-declared move assignment operator, and
> - `X` does not have a user-declared destructor.

Declaring a copy operator or assignment operator as `delete`d still counts as declaring it.

The solution is of course to declare the move operations for `uncopiable`.

```
uncopiable(uncopiable&&) noexcept = default;
uncopiable& operator=(uncopiable&&) noexcept = default;
```

Note that the [move operations should usually be declared `noexcept`](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rc-move-noexcept).  Especially if you want to use the type in a `std::vector` like in your example.

Comment: I don't think the `noexcept` is necessary, those explicitly defaulted constructors should implicitly be `noexcept`: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/mGzep1B9eLmOsiFE Of course, there's no harm in adding it.

Comment: @dyp I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

This compiles ok on MinGw:

```
#include <vector>

class uncopiable {
    using self = uncopiable;
protected:
    uncopiable() {}
    ~uncopiable() {}
    uncopiable(const self&) = delete;
    self& operator=(const self&) = delete;
};

struct A {
    struct B : uncopiable {
        using self = B;

        B() {
        }

        B(B&&) {};
        self& operator=(B&&) = default;

        ~B() {
        }
    };

    A() { v.emplace_back(); }
    ~A() {}

private:
    std::vector<B> v;
};

int main () {
    A* a = new A();
}
```